# MySQL Self Join Table Next/Prev Row Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, groupwise-maximum

I have a table that has a column `Sequence` that provides ordering for the table. I'm trying to get the next and previous rows joined together based off of `Sequence` so I can get the previous and next SKU values.

The table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Builder` (
    `Shipment Number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SKU` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Pallet Number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Sequence` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,

    INDEX `Primary Index` (`Shipment Number`, `Pallet Number`, `Sequence`) USING BTREE
)
```

My query currently looks something like this for computing the next rows SKU value:

```
SELECT
    B1.`SKU`,
    B1.`Shipment Number`,
    B1.`Pallet Number`,
    B1.`Sequence`,
    B2.`SKU`
FROM Builder B1

LEFT JOIN Builder B2 ON
    B2.`Sequence.` = (
        SELECT MIN(B3.`Sequence.`)
        FROM Builder B3
        WHERE
            B3.`Sequence` > B1.`Sequence` AND
            B3.`Shipment Number` = B1.`Shipment Number` AND
            B3.`Pallet Number` = B1.`Pallet Number`
    ) AND
    B1.`Shipment Number` = B2.`Shipment Number` AND
    B1.`Pallet Number` = B2.`Pallet Number`
```

I have added an Index to the `Builder` table for `(Sequence, Shipment Number, Pallet Number)`.

The query computes the next SKU correctly but the performance is pretty terrible, even running on a subset of my full dataset (50,000 rows) takes a few minutes. I'm not sure if there's anything else I can do to improve this queries performance.

Running on MySQL 8.0.20.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script (and data example, 3-5 adjacent rows) and precise MySQL version.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x, consider using window functions like `LAG()`.

Comment: In stead of `SELECT MIN(Sequence)`, you could also do `SELECT Sequence..... ORDER BY..... LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the suggestion. I tried running the query using `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` instead but it looks like the performance is slightly worse that the `MIN` Implementation. @Barmar I was trying to avoid using window functions as the business requirement is to be in ANSI sql.

Comment: Is there any `WHERE` clause?  Or do you want the entire table dumped?

Comment: It sounds a bit like "groupwise max"; see the tag I added.  There are much faster ways to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEAD()` and `LAG()` instead of joins. They were made for this.

For example:

```
select
  *,
  lag(`SKU`) over(partition by `Shipment Number`, `Pallet Number`
                  order by `Sequence`) as prev_sku,
  lead(`SKU`) over(partition by `Shipment Number`, `Pallet Number`
                   order by `Sequence`) as next_sku
from builder
```

`LAG()` returns the value of the previous row, according to the specified criteria (*partition* and *ordering*), while `LEAD()` returns the value of the next row according the specified criteria.

You can also add an optional second parameter (an integer that defaults to `1`) to indicate how far away (rows) you want to peek at.

Comment: This was significantly faster than my implementation. Thanks!